# Why can't I insert this data into my fact table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
INSERT INTO stage.FactPitch(GameID, AtBatID, BatterID, PitcherID, PitchType, Code, Date, Zone, px, pz, SpinRate, SpinDirection, x0, y0, z0, pfx_x, pfx_z, vx0, vy0, vz0, BreakAngle, BreakLength, Break_Y, StartSpeed, EndSpeed, TypeConfidence, Nasty, PitcherScore, BatterScore)

SELECT
     g.g_id
    ,a.ab_id
    ,pn.id
    ,pn2.id
    ,p.type
    ,p.code
    ,g.date 
    ,p.zone
    ,p.px
    ,p.pz
    ,p.spin_rate
    ,p.spin_dir
    ,p.x0
    ,p.y0
    ,p.z0
    ,p.pfx_x
    ,p.pfx_z
    ,p.vx0
    ,p.vy0
    ,p.vz0
    ,p.break_angle
    ,p.break_length
    ,p.break_y
    ,p.start_speed
    ,p.end_speed
    ,p.type_confidence
    ,p.nasty
    ,a.p_score
    ,p.b_score
FROM dbo.Pitches p
LEFT JOIN dbo.AtBats a
    ON p.ab_id = a.ab_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.Games g
    ON g.g_id = a.g_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.PlayerNames pn
    ON pn.id = a.batter_id
LEFT JOIN dbo.PlayerNames pn2
    ON pn2.id = a.pitcher_id
ORDER BY a.ab_id
```

When I run this query to insert my information into my stage fact table I get one of two errors.
If I run the entire query I get:

"Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 148. Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric."

When I run just the INSERT statement line alone I get:

"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 148 Incorrect syntax near ')'."

I know the error must line within line 148. All of my other staging tables are completely fine, and when I run the SELECT statement and everything else below the data pulls fine. Anyone have an idea as to what this could be?

Comment: Compare the column types of FactPitch with the data returned from the query. Seemingly a mismatch in one or more of them. And FWIW, I would consider renaming column "Date" to something else such as "game_date" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Isolated I imported all of my source data as nvarchar(500), so everything is being captured. When creating my other staging dimensions, the data read in just fine with the source files being imported as that datatype.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server is unable to convert one of the NVARCHAR values in your SELECT statement into a NUMERIC value -- potentially because it contains non-numeric characters.

Double-check the data types in your source and destination tables. There is a mismatch there somewhere.

You can do this quickly by executing your SELECT query on its own, inserting the results into a temp table.

E.g.

```sql
SELECT  g.g_id, ...
INTO    #TempTable
FROM    dbo.Pitches p...
```

Then, in the same session window, you can query the [tempdb] database to see how it generated the data types, based in the data it read.

```sql
USE [tempdb] ;
GO
SELECT          t.[name] AS [table_name]
                , c.[name] AS [column_name]
                , c.[column_id]
                , c.[collation_name]
                , dt.[name] AS [data_type]
                , dt.[max_length]
FROM            sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN  sys.all_columns AS c
        ON      t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
    INNER JOIN  sys.types AS dt
        ON      c.[user_type_id] = dt.[system_type_id]
WHERE           t.[name] LIKE '#TempTable%'
    AND         dt.[name] <> 'sysname'
ORDER BY        c.[column_id] ASC ;
```

Which ever column has the mismatch, you'll either need to adjust the data type on your destination table or CAST or CONVERT the source column to match the destination data type.

As for the second error you mentioned -- `Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 148 Incorrect syntax near ')'."` -- this is because SQL Server can't find any values  to insert, after the bracket close. Once you sort the data type mismatch out this will be fine too.